# PHPMyAdmin and mySQL: Insert into existing database, not create new one. Error "Can't create database; database exists"

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently went to backup a database and got the following error "#1007 - Can't create database 'wordpress_8'; database exists".

I have the following line in the beginning of my sql file:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: 'wordpress_8'
--
CREATE DATABASE wordpress_8 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE wordpress_8;
```

What do I need to change this to in order to insert the subsequent data into the existing "wordpress_8" database rather than create a new one?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you backing up a database (as you said), or restoring one?  Could you edit the question to be clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change which database you're using, you use the `USE` statement.  In this case, `USE wordpress_8;`.  Then the actual data needs to be inserted into the tables using `INSERT` statements.

Comment: thanks! just removing "CREATE DATABASE wordpress_8 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;" worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure a clean restore, I would add:

```
DROP DATABASE wordpress_8;
```

Else you're potentially merging two databases, which can get ugly.

Answer (score -1):

Delete

```
CREATE DATABASE wordpress_8 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

and Imropt again ))